# How can I recieve an RTP stream with JavaCV?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, javacv

I'm trying to stream video from an RTP server (currently VLC for testing) and decode it in Java. To do this, I'm using [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) to decode the incoming stream. Here's what I have so far:

```
try {
    grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtp://localhost:5004/test");
    grabber.setFormat("h264");
    grabber.setFrameRate(30.0);
    grabber.start();
    Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    while (true) {
        Frame frame = grabber.grab();
        imageToDraw = frame != null ? converter.convert(frame) : null;
        // goes off to paint a widget on a window, see https://git.io/fhZSr for more context
        repaint();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: Discover what circumstances cause this
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

On VLC, my stream settings are set like this:

- Destination stream: RTP/TS (address `localhost`, port 5004, and stream name `test`.)
- Transcoding active, set to "Video - H.264 + MP3 (TS)" preset:

  - MPEG-TS encapsulation
  - h.264 video with MPEG audio
- Stream all elementary streams is **off.**

I can get one VLC instance to stream to another with these settings (with the "client" VLC receiving from `rtp://localhost:5004/test`), and it works just fine. (The only issues arise from having a weak test machine not suited transcoding high res video.)

Switch over to Java, and all I can see is gray frames with a spat of color here and there. The console is also screaming the whole way through. Some snippets (the full log is too long to be a reasonable post, but it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/c-x-berger/0d1208e85254824b56a94ef80102f0f0) if you really want it):

```
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 8 12
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] error while decoding MB 8 12, bytestream 670
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] concealing 421 DC, 421 AC, 421 MV errors in P frame
```

---

```
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] Reference 4 >= 2
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] error while decoding MB 25 8, bytestream 416
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] concealing 556 DC, 556 AC, 556 MV errors in B frame
```

---

```
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] Reference 5 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] error while decoding MB 21 1, bytestream 6042
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] concealing 826 DC, 826 AC, 826 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] Invalid NAL unit 8, skipping.
[above line repeats 5x]
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] error while decoding MB 3 0, bytestream 730
[h264 @ 0x7f6c4c3502c0] concealing 836 DC, 836 AC, 836 MV errors in P frame
```

Is there something I am clearly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you have to tell FFmpegFrameGrabber the correct format and codes. Your format is not H.264 since you are sending a MPEG-2 Transport Stream.
Try setting the format (setFormat) to "mpegts".
The video codec to some H.264 decoder and the audio codec to some MPEG-2 Layer 3 decoder (MP3).

The assume the error messages are resulting from the H.264 decoder trying to read a MEPG-2 Transport Stream.

Comment: For me, calling `grabber.setFormat("ts")` throws `av_find_input_format() error: Could not find input format "ts".` Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: Please try "mpegts".